# ExcelScript - run on cell selection / editing (bind?)

Tags: excel, office-scripts, excel-online

How can I run a piece of code on a cell selection? And how can I run it again, when I start editing the value in the cell?

I been going through the documentation, and in no way I can find anything (a specific binding???) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852529/how-to-handle-event-on-data-change-in-excel-sheet-to-refresh-all-pivot-tables), it looks like it's not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `workbook.getActiveCell()` to run a piece of code on a cell selection, but the second part to your question is not possible as Office Scripts does not support events that trigger scripts to run.